# Crawl web page encoding issue - negative value in byte

Tags: java, encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x, web-crawler

I use following code to crawl a web page.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(entity.getContentType());
//output: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I found that the character "’" has the byte value -110, which cannot be mapped to a valid character in either iso-8859-1 or utf-8.

I try to manually open the page and copy the character and save as a text file, then I saw the byte value is actually 39. **I think the OS did the conversion when the character gone through the clipboard**

What I want is just to save the web page as original to local disk.

I made a simple code to save the content to disk. I directly read bytes and write bytes. When I open the saved file with Hex Editor, I can see the value of the byte is 146 (-110).

```
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/test.html"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = 0;
while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    buffer = new byte[1024];
}
in.close();
fos.close();
```

So now the issue become how to reconstruct the character from the byte 146(-110). I will keep trying and update if I got anything.

Comment: Could you provide code which have issue with "’" character? And code you are using to save web page to disk if it's not the same. [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could give some code how you save the page to the disk? And did you check the value for `’`?
It looks like the character `’` is 3 bytes long unless my pasting or your copying failed. Check this out:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c = '’';
    System.out.println("character: " + c);
    System.out.println("int: " + (int)c);
    String s = new String("’");
    // Java uses UTF-16 encoding, other encodings will give different values
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    System.out.println("bytes: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
}
```

Edit: I've found the following suggested approach to charset handling, give it a try:

```
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
    Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), charset);
```

Source: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1):

A byte in Java is a signed type with a value of -128 to 127. The most significant bit is used to indicate the sign. For example, 0111 1111 == 127, and 1000 0000 == -128.

I looked up your character (’) in an ANSI table and found that it has a value of 146 (which is of course greater than 127). The binary representation is 1001 0010, and so interpreting this as a signed value will yield -110.

To reproduce what you are seeing:

```
String s = new String("’");            // ’ is ansi character 146
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();           
System.out.println( (int)bytes[0] );   // prints -110
```

To convert the byte value to an unsigned representation:

```
char c = (char)(bytes[0] & 0xFF);
System.out.println( (int)c );          // prints 146
```